# SonarQube Measures: Adding Multiple Contain Filters

Tags: sonarqube

I'm curious if anyone has attempted to add multiple contains (key or name) filters and "OR" them together. Currently, if I add two contain filters the search doesn't return anything because both values aren't in the key or name. I'm attempting to get a subset of packages in a project to show up in the dashboard widget. There's not a unique string I can use without pulling in the entire "my favorites" list. I could add multiple of the same widget where each widget would have one key or name filter, but I figured I would see if anyone knows a better way. I've checked the documentation and jira, but didn't find anything that would help me achieve what I'm trying to do.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported but there is an open ticket, which is not resolved yet: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2653.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I wasn't searching with the appropriate keywords to find that.